# преобразование sys.argv в (*args, **kwargs)

Tags: python, аргументы, argv

Как правильно преобразовать аргументы командной строки в (*args, **kwargs) с помощью sys.argv?
Есть некоторая функция:

```
def test(*a, **b):
    return print(a), print(b)

test('arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3', first='1', two='2', three='3')
```

Результат (все логично):

```
('arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3')
{'first': '1', 'two': '2', 'three': '3'}
```

Если попытаться передать те же аргументы через командную строку:

```
python3.8 code.py 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3', first='1', two='2', three='3'
```

и видоизменить саму функцию:

```
import sys

def test(*a, **b):
    return print(a), print(b)

test(' '.join(sys.argv[1:]))

python3.8 args_.py 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3', first='1', two='2', three='3'
('arg1, arg2, arg3, first=1, two=2, three=3',)
{}
```

Comment: Советую ознакомиться с модулем argparse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандартного решения для такого варианта нет. Обычно используют различные библиотеки для разбора аргументов командной строки от стандартного [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) до [click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/), например. Но там используется другой формат примерно такого вида:

```
python3 code.py arg1 arg2 arg3 --first=1 --two=2 --three=3
```

Обзор различных библиотек для разбора параметров командной строки можно почитать в этой статье: [Сравнение популярных CLI-библиотек для Python: click, cement, fire и другие](https://habr.com/ru/post/466999/)

Простое "наколеночное" решение для вашего формата:

```
import sys
import ast

def test(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args)
    print(kwargs)


print(sys.argv[1:])
args = []
kwargs = {}
for item in sys.argv[1:]:
    item = item.rstrip(',')
    if item:  # Пустой элемент, например если была одиночная запятая
        try:
            args.append(ast.literal_eval(item))
        except (ValueError, SyntaxError):
            if "=" not in item:
                args.append(item)
            else:
                key, value = item.split("=", maxsplit=1)
                try:
                    kwargs[key] = ast.literal_eval(value)
                except ValueError:
                    kwargs[key] = value

test(*args, **kwargs)
```

Вывод:

```
$ python3 test_args.py 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3', first='1', two=2, three='3'
['arg1,', 'arg2,', 'arg3,', 'first=1,', 'two=2,', 'three=3']
('arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3')
{'first': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
```

Все кавычки при при передаче через командную строку потерялись, поэтому числа в кавычках стали просто числами. Если нужно передавать именно строки, можно упростить код убрав попытки конвертации при помощи `ast.literal_eval` (все параметры будут считаться строками):

```
import sys


def test(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args)
    print(kwargs)


print(sys.argv[1:])
args = []
kwargs = {}
for item in sys.argv[1:]:
    item = item.rstrip(',')
    if item:  # Пустой элемент, например если была одиночная запятая
        if "=" not in item:
            args.append(item)
        else:
            key, value = item.split("=", maxsplit=1)
            kwargs[key] = value

test(*args, **kwargs)
```

Вывод будет такой:

```
$ python3 test_args.py 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3', first='1', two=2, three='3'
['arg1,', 'arg2,', 'arg3,', 'first=1,', 'two=2,', 'three=3']
('arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3')
{'first': '1', 'two': '2', 'three': '3'}
```